# How to get index value from list in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have following set of keywords
set keywords {a b c d}. I want to print index value of c. How to do this in tcl?

Answer (score 1):

With [`lsearch`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm)

```
% set keywords {a b c d}
a b c d
% set idx [lsearch -exact $keywords "c"]
2
```